# Trying to write a unit test for a simple python adventure game

Tags: python

I'm new in python and I just need a little help on unit test. This is the code I'm trying to test

```
rooms = {
'Walls': {
    'name': 'an empty room',
    'east': 'bedroom',
    'north': 'temple',
    'text': 'The stone floors and walls and cold and damp.'
},
'temple': {
    'name': 'a small temple',
    'east': 'torture',
    'south': 'empty',
    'text': 'There are three rows of benches facing a small statue.'
},
'torture': {
    'name':
    'a torture chamber',
    'west':
    'temple',
    'south':
    'bedroom',
    'text':
    'There is a rack and an iron maiden against the wall\nand some chains and thumbscrews on the floor.'
},
'bedroom': {
    'name': 'a bedroom',
    'north': 'torture',
    'west': 'empty',
    'text': 'There is a large bed with black, silk sheets on it.'
}
}

directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
current_room = rooms['Walls']

# game loop

while True:
    # display current location
    print()
    print(directions)
    print()
    print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
    print(current_room['text'])
    # get user input
    command = input('\nWhat do you do? ').strip()
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        else:
            # bad movement
            print("You can’t move further in this direction.")
    # quit game
    elif command.lower() in ('q', 'quit'):
        break
    # bad command
    else:
        print("Invalid command")
```

Comment: Start with small examples. Look at the demos. Don't attempt to do something THAT big without gaining some experience first.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code with a function. (Lets call it 'adv_game()').
The game/function should not print anything.It should return status codes.
Example:

1. Status 1 ==> You can move in this direction
2. Status 2 ==> Invalid command
3. Etc

You will have another code that will call this 'adv_game()' function with the 'rooms' data structure and the current user room. The caller code will do the interaction with the user based on the adv_game()' return value.
The UnitTest will feed the 'adv_game()' with combinations of input and will match the result against expected value